# Aggregated distinct from find results

Tags: json, mongodb

First of all `db.collection.distinct("name");` gives not bad result for me, but the problem is that distinct has limitation (results must not be larger than the maximum BSON size), and I need to aggregate through it, right?

Another things is that I really want to do distinct from find filtered results, so from something like this:

`db.collection.find({ name: { $exists: true, $ne: null }, state: "published" });`

So the main idea is to save all published "name" values from full collection without any limitation in the json file.

So I used:

```
>cat 1.json
db.collection.distinct("name");
mongo db < 1.json > 2.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query is:

> db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{name: { $exists: true, $ne: null },
>   state: "published" }},{$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet:
>   "$name"}}}]);